# Why the attributes of a object in __init__() and get_context_data() different?

Tags: django, python-3.x, view

```
class SomeView(DetailView) :
    def __init__(self, *kwargs):
        print(type(self), dir(self)) 
    def get_context_data:
        print(type(self), dir(self))
```

__ init__ does not prints "request attribute" for dir(self), but get_context_data() prints.

Why such a difference?

Answer (score 2):

The request is *not* set by the `__init__` of the view. Indeed, it is set by the [**`setup`** function](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/views/generic/base.py#L83-L87):

> ```
>     def setup(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>         """Initialize attributes shared by all view methods."""
>         self.request = request
>         self.args = args
>         self.kwargs = kwargs
> ```

This setup is done *after* the `View` object is constructed. Indeed, if you use `.as_view()` it returns a function that basically is the [**`view`** function](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/views/generic/base.py#L61-L71):

> ```
>         def view(request, *args, **kwargs):
>             self = cls(**initkwargs)
>             if hasattr(self, 'get') and not hasattr(self, 'head'):
>                 self.head = self.get
>             self.setup(request, *args, **kwargs)
>             if not hasattr(self, 'request'):
>                 raise AttributeError(
>                     "%s instance has no 'request' attribute. Did you override "
>                     "setup() and forget to call super()?" % cls.__name__
>                 )
>             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
> ```

It thus first constructs a `self` (with `self = cls(**initkwargs)`), and then will call `self.setup(request, *args, **kwargs)` to set the `request` object together with the `args` and `kwargs`.

If you need to do something *after* the `request` is set, you can thus override the `setup` method. For example:

```
class SomeView(DetailView):

    def setup(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().setup(*args, **kwargs)
        print(dir)
```

Comment: How to override setup() method ?  the last line print(dir) in setup() is not executing? When will it execute?

Comment: How to make init() method executing twice? 
 [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60650878/how-to-stop-init-of-a-class-based-view-executing-twice-in-django?noredirect=1#comment107304367_60650878

Comment: @MounikaBathina: well the `setup` method is only defined since Django-2.2. Before that, the `request`, etc. was set in the `view` function itself.